# how to add 'glyphicon glyphicon-user' and 'glyphicon glyphicon log-in' in this code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, glyphicons

My code which is coming wrong:
This is what i have tried but it is coming wrong

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"> <%= link_to 'SignUp',   {:controller =>'users', :action => 'new'} %></span> </li>
  <li> <span class="glyphicon-log-in"> <%= link_to 'LogIn', {:controller =>'sessions', :action => 'new'} %></span> </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you please expand on "coming wrong"? what do you observe? Can you show it to us? What do you expect to see instead? Edit your question and add any relevant code and html into there (don't reply in comments because the formatting is awful) :)

Comment: I mean it is not showing any glyphs

Comment: Then say that - because that's what we need to know to help you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li> <%= link_to raw('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>'),   {:controller =>'users', :action => 'new'} %> </li>
  <li> <%= link_to raw('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>'), {:controller =>'sessions', :action => 'new'} %> </li>
</ul>
```

Your links should wrap your icons, not the other way around. If it's still not working, it's likely due to you not including the relevant icon font or css files correctly in your project. If it's still not working, update your question with a screenshot of what it looks like, and also the relevant code where you're including Bootstrap's css and fonts.

Comment: So add the words into the wrapped spans... I suspect that Joshua gave you indicative results - not literally what you'll need.